# Firestore - access a number value in a document

Tags: android, database, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a simple number value in one of my documents in Firestore Database, which I am trying to get. So far, I have only done it for String Objects and Custom Objects:

```
String wkCategory = task.getResult().getString("setting");
```

So I thought it should be the same for numbers. I know its only possible to get Long or Doubles, so I tried this:

```
int time = task.getResult().getLong("duration").intValue();
```

and this:

```
Number time = task.getResult().getLong("duration").intValue();
```

I then pass on the value in a bundle to the next fragment, where it is set in a TextView.

```
private int time;
Bundle bundle =getArguments();
if(null!=bundle) {
   time=bundle.getInt("Time");
}
TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
time.setText(time.toString());
```

However, this is, what appears in my TextView. As I said, it works normally with Strings. Cant figure it out though, cause I even use the

```
.toString OR +""
```

[Screenshot of the TextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cnVr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You having issues with variable names.

Make sure give different names for each variable for understanding.

```
private int time;
Bundle bundle =getArguments();
if(null!=bundle) {
   time=bundle.getInt("Time");
}
TextView timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
timeView.setText(time + "");
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please check out the topics named: "Boxed and primitive types" and "Implicit and Explicit conversion or casting" to figure out where to use toString() or not